# How to set named argument for string.Format?

Tags: c#, string, named-parameters

I have C# error when calling:

```
string.Format(format:"abbccc", 1,22);
```

The error is *"Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified"*

How can I fix this?

**[Edit]**

I prefer to use named parameters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to specify the name of the format argument, you have to specify the name of the following argument also:

```
string.Format(format:"abbccc", arg0:1, arg1:22);
```

That's not very useful, as the names "arg0" and "arg1" doesn't say anything at all about the arguments.

Also, there are only overloads up to "arg2", so if you have more arguments, you have to put them in an array to name the argument:

```
string.Format(format:"abbccc", args:new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

You can simply skip naming the arguments:

```
string.Format("abbccc", 1, 22);
```

Answer (score 1):

**In my case, I had to Clean and Rebuild the solution, that made the error go away**. What happened was, I added an argument like this

```cs
sched.ScheduleJob(Jobdetail:job, trigger);
```

I was getting an error for trigger, so I removed, JobDetail:, and the syntax error go away but on complication I was still getting the error

> Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments
> have been specified

I cleaned the solution and rebuilt and the error went away.