# Can named arguments be used with the params modifier?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to invoke `Invoke` on a `Dispatcher` using the following overload:

```
public object Invoke(Delegate method, params object[] args);
```

I want to use named arguments, but I can't seem to find the syntax for the argument with the params modifier. All of the following won't compile:

```
dispatcher.Invoke(method: () => { }, args: {});
dispatcher.Invoke(method: () => { }, args: new object[0]);
dispatcher.Invoke(method: () => { }, args: null);
dispatcher.Invoke(method: () => { }, args: new object[] {});
object[] foo = {};
dispatcher.Invoke(method: () => { }, args: foo);
dispatcher.Invoke(method: () => { }, args: new[] {"Hello", "World!"});
```

I found these two questions to which there seems to be no definite answers:

[Named parameters with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871927/named-parameters-with-params)

[How to set named argument for string.Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059330/how-to-set-named-argument-for-string-format)

So my question is: can it be done or not? If yes, how?

**UDPATE**

Daniel Hilgarth's shows that yes `params` can be used with named parameters. I integrated his answer using this pattern:

```
Action method = () => { };
if (_dispatcher != null)
    _dispatcher.Invoke(method: method, args: null);
else
    method();
```

Comment: First question is mine and seems there is no way. You must go without params.

Comment: You say "seems"; it would be nice to have a definite answer ;-)

Comment: Please specify the exact compiler error. It works for me when I change `Delegate` to `Action` so it is not a problem of the `params` keyword.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: can you post how you made it work as an answer?

Comment: @ChuckNorris: turns out it can be done....

Comment: Not the way he wanted. He wanted to do something like this: `dispatcher.Invoke(method: method, args: "Hello", "World");`. Note that there is no array passed to the named parameter `args`, but a list of comma separated values.

Comment: I want to say the same as @DanielHilgarth :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code compiles without problems:

```
void Main()
{
    Invoke(method: () => {}, args: new object[] {});
}

public object Invoke(Action method, params object[] args)
{
    return null;
}
```

I had to change the type of the first parameter from `Delegate` to `Action` to make it compile, because `() => {}` can't be converted to `Delegate`.

Alternatively, the following does also compile:

```
void Main()
{
    Action method = () => {};
    Invoke(method: method, args: new object[] {});
}

public object Invoke(Delegate method, params object[] args)
{
    return null;
}
```

My assumption is that you never got a compile error about the `args` parameter but about the `method` parameter saying "*Cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Delegate'*". This problem is solved by either casting the lambda to an Action (`Invoke(method: (Action)(() => {}) ...`) or by defining a variable of type `Action` that is passed as parameter to the method (see above), because `Action` can implicitly be converted to `Delegate`.

Comment: +1 Not only does this word fine, this helped me create what I think is more readable code. I will update to demosntrate.

Comment: @sixfeetsix: Yes, the new code looks very nice and clean, aside from the unnecessary use of named parameters in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Have a try;

```
dispatcher.Invoke(method: () => { }, args: new[] {"Hello", "World!"});
```

Comment: Actually yes :) and it doesn't work either; I'll add it to my list.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I expect no problems. Like the following; object[] a = new object[] { "x", "y" };

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Not correct. This works. arrays in C# have always been covariant.